# php mail doesn't send from yahoo to gmail

Tags: php, function, email

I have created a contact form using mail function, everything just fine but there is a problem by sending mail from yahoo to gmail!
any email to any email is good(even from gmail to yahoo).
But when the email goes from yahoo to gmail, it dose not work!

Like this:

```
mail("myemail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From :myemail@yahoo.com");
```

This dose not work!
how to fix this?

whole code:

```
    <?php
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$email;
    $subject=$form_name." - ".$subject;
    $message=nl2br($message);
    $message=$message."<br /><br /><br />".$name."<br />".$phone."<br />".$web;
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
    if(mail($send_to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        echo "<p class='success'><span></span> ".$success."</p>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p class='error'><span></span> there was a problem, please try again</p>";
    };
    ?>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what is your problem :)

Comment: if i set the from-email=some@yahoo.com and send-to=some@gmail.com, it dose not work!

Comment: Can you add an example of what you write when it does work?

Comment: this works: mail("myemail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"FROM :myemail@gmail.com"); this dose not work: mail("myemail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"FROM :myemail@yahoo.com");

Comment: Did you look at spam section?

Comment: Paste whole code in your question!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is failing due to a security check - your server is not associated with Yahoo.com, thus when the origin IP address of the e-mail is checked against the domain of the sender e-mail address, it fails and the e-mail is blocked. Only some e-mail providers do this level of checking.

If your goal is to have your yahoo e-mail address show as the reply to address, try setting it using the `reply-to:` header instead of the `from:` header. See the PHP mail() docs for more specifics. Use the appropriate or default from address of your domain or server. This will give you the best results as far as making sure your e-mails actually get delivered.

Comment: the problem is, this is working just fine: mail("myemail@any.com",$subject,$message,"FROM :myemail@yahoo.com"); problem is just when i try to send to gmail, i can send yahoo to yahoo,gmail to yahoo,gmail to gmail,... but can't send yahoo to gmail!!

Comment: Yes, as stated in my answer, only some ISPs will check that the e-mail originated from a server with an IP address registered to the domain of the FROM: address. Gmail, Comcast and AOL (plus many small companies) are the only ones I know of that do it.

Comment: well, is that Usual? should i do any thing as programmer?

Comment: Your best bet is to send e-mail from your website's domain. Your hosting company will usually provide you with an e-mail account for site business.

Answer (score 0):

When your mail server is sending an email, the DNS SPF record is checked to ensure that your server is allowed to send emails where from address is set to `yahoo.com` or `gmail.com`. If there is no SPF records which tells that your server is allowed to send emails for `yahoo.com` domain, this means that your server is maybe sending a SPAM. This way, some mail servers can reject emails received from your server.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the same problem by moving the sender email address from the "from" header to the "reply-to" header.

Set From with something like "no-answer@yourmail.com"

Set Reply-to (add a line in your code) with the sender email address.

Gmail will no longer filtrate the mail, considering it's a transparent behavior and then not a spam attempt.

Though the problem occurs only with Yahoo/Gmail…